# For hibernate entity class, can i pick property from instance variable class to set a column

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, entity

I want to persist JSON objects in Db with hibernate and spring boot.

I have sample JSON with me with which i want to generate POJO and Hibernate Entity class. I will ignore some fields using @transient property. But i want some field's property as a column in by db.

eg:

```
{
  "CompanyName": "Books by Bessie",
  "DisplayName": "Books by Bessie",
  "PrintOnCheckName": "Books by Bessie",
  "Active": true,
  "PrimaryPhone": {
    "FreeFormNumber": "(650) 555-7745"
  },
}
```

I want to persist this JSON . For **`PrimaryPhone`** I want to fetch **`FreeFormNumber`** and put it in db under the column name **`PrimaryPhone`** . Of course I am trying to avoid writing separate pojo and entity class and a mapper.

PS: Is there a tool to generate hibernate entity classes from JSON?

Comment: No. You should design your entity model or DB first and then map the data

Comment: You can try to use hibernate [dynamic model](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#dynamic-model).

Comment: @SternK Nice Find!!!